# How to get IE 10 to show all options in a long datalist

Tags: html, internet-explorer-10, html-datalist

I have a situation where I'm using an HTML Datalist and text input for users to select or type in a state, where there are a long list of options. Firefox and Chrome will enable a scrollbar to be able to select options further down the list that aren't initially visible. In Chrome this ability is enabled when you use the autocomplete="off" attribute. IE 10 unfortunately doesn't show a scrollbar in any case that I'm aware of, so the user can't see or select what is initially visible, even if they attempt to key down to the bottom of the list.

Does anyone know of a solution to get IE 10 to show a scrollbar on a very long datalist?

You can see my example on JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/amGY9/15/

```
<datalist id="states_list">
    <option value="0">Alabama</option>
    <option value="1">Alaska</option>
    <option value="56">American Samoa</option>
    <option value="2">Arizona</option>
    <option value="3">Arkansas</option>
    <option value="62">Army Europe (PO)</option>
    <option value="4">California</option>
    <option value="54">Canal Zone</option>
    <option value="5">Colorado</option>
    <option value="6">Connecticut</option>
    <option value="7">Delaware</option>
    <option value="8">District of Columbia</option>
    <option value="9">Florida</option>
    <option value="10">Georgia</option>
    <option value="52">Guam</option>
    <option value="11">Hawaii</option>
    <option value="12">Idaho</option>
    <option value="13">Illinois</option>
    <option value="14">Indiana</option>
    <option value="15">Iowa</option>
    <option value="16">Kansas</option>
    <option value="17">Kentucky</option>
    <option value="18">Louisiana</option>
    <option value="19">Maine</option>
    <option value="53">Mariana Islands</option>
    <option value="60">Marshall Islands</option>
    <option value="20">Maryland</option>
    <option value="21">Massachusetts</option>
    <option value="22">Michigan</option>
    <option value="59">Micronesia</option>
    <option value="23">Minnesota</option>
    <option value="24">Mississippi</option>
    <option value="25">Missouri</option>
    <option value="26">Montana</option>
    <option value="27">Nebraska</option>
    <option value="28">Nevada</option>
    <option value="29">New Hampshire</option>
    <option value="30">New Jersey</option>
    <option value="31">New Mexico</option>
    <option value="32">New York</option>
    <option value="33">North Carolina</option>
    <option value="34">North Dakota</option>
    <option value="35">Ohio</option>
    <option value="36">Oklahoma</option>
    <option value="37">Oregon</option>
    <option value="58">Pacific Trust Terr.</option>
    <option value="61">Palau Islands</option>
    <option value="38">Pennsylvania</option>
    <option value="51">Puerto Rico</option>
    <option value="39">Rhode Island</option>
    <option value="40">South Carolina</option>
    <option value="41">South Dakota</option>
    <option value="42">Tennessee</option>
    <option value="43">Texas</option>
    <option value="57">US Outlying Islands</option>
    <option value="44">Utah</option>
    <option value="45">Vermont</option>
    <option value="55">Virgin Islands</option>
    <option value="46">Virginia</option>
    <option value="47">Washington</option>
    <option value="48">West Virginia</option>
    <option value="49">Wisconsin</option>
    <option value="50">Wyoming</option>
</datalist>
<input type="search" id="state" name="state" list="states_list" placeholder="Start typing or click" autocomplete="off">
```

Comment: This is still buggy in many browsers.  I wouldn't rely on this in any production site.  I can give you multiple examples of inconsistent behaviors in the same browser and across browsers.  Is there a reason to use this over a dropdown/autocomplete library?

Comment: Well, my rationale was based on our dependency of using jQuery 1.4.2, and I haven't found jQuery autocomplete solutions that's reasonably accessible that use that jQuery version. Now I'm thinking perhaps I should load a newer jQuery in addition to use an autocomplete plugin we could use as a fallback, even though it would be another script to load.

Comment: I know this is late, but I just checked this in IE 11, and it has a scrollbar working perfectly. Don't know about IE 10.